# Why is nuget trying for force and dependency upgrade when I install fluentNhibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nuget

I already have nhibernate in a project (version 3.3.1) already and now I am trying to download fluentNhibernate through Nuget package manager and I get this error:

```
PM> install-package fluentnhibernate -Version 1.3.0.733
Attempting to resolve dependency 'NHibernate (≥ 3.3.1.4000)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Iesi.Collections (≥ 3.2 && < 4.0)'.
Successfully installed 'Iesi.Collections 3.2.0.4000'.
Successfully installed 'NHibernate 3.3.2.4000'.
Successfully installed 'FluentNHibernate 1.3.0.733'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
install-package : Updating 'NHibernate 3.1.0.4000' to 'NHibernate 3.3.2.4000' failed.     
Unable to find a version of 'NHibernate.Castle' that is compatible with 'NHibernate 
3.3.2.4000'.

At line:1 char:1
+ install-package fluentnhibernate -Version 1.3.0.733
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I don't understand why this doesn't succeed as it says nhibernate just need to be version 3.3.1 or higher so why is it trying to force an upgrade to 3.3.2 (i want to keep it at 3.3.1) which then isn't compatible with castle.

Is there any explanation for this or is there any workaround that will install fluentnhibernate but keep nhibernate at the current version (which it says is fine)?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: According to the output you have NHibernate 3.1.0.4000 and not `3.3.1` what you've mentioned in your post... can you run the `Get-Package` command to list the currently installed  packages and post the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's trying to upgrade to NH 3.3.2 because this is the latest version that meets the dependencies of Fluent NHibernate. I see no reason to prefer 3.3.1 over 3.3.2. What you already have is 3.1.0 which is much older.

You also have the package NHibernate.Castle installed, which is limited to 3.1.0.4000 only.

To summarize:

- FluentNHibernate 1.3.0.733 needs NHibernate 3.3.1 or later.
- NHibernate.Castle 3.1.0 needs NHibernate 3.1.0.

Since no later version of NHibernate.Castle is available, this cannot be resolved.

Starting with NH 3.2 you don't need NHibernate.Castle (or similar) anymore, as the proxy-generation is now built in. Unless you need this for some other reason, you can just remove that package.

See also [Constraining Upgrades To Allowed Versions](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning#Constraining_Upgrades_To_Allowed_Versions) in the NuGet reference.

Comment: One possible reason to retain NHibernate.Castle is that the built in proxy generation has some serious compatibility problems with some FNH codebases that were written with FNH + Castle - I've had to stay with an older version of FNH because of this.